# Get ApplicationIcon from Code in NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

In the .csproj I assign an icon to my .NET Core 3.0 application:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ApplicationIcon>C:\temp\myicon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The icon gets set for the generated exe file and shown in task-manager/file explorer.

How can I access this icon from code? I don't want to extract it from generated exe or add an additional resource icon.

Answer (score 2):

you can extract like this

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;         //For Icon
using System.Reflection;      //For Assembly

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //Gets the icon associated with the currently executing assembly
                //(or pass a different file path and name for a different executable)
                Icon appIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);                
            }
            catch(ArgumentException ae) 
            {
                //handle
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//We can use this statement.

using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {       
                Icon appIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);                
            }
            catch(ArgumentException ae) 
            {
                //handle
            }
```